# Zsh use an array in a find command

Tags: zsh, array, parameter

I would like to `rsync` over a few files, specified with an array, and delete any other file in a directory.

The only approach I can think of is to remove other files using `find`, and `rsync` over the files, so we copy as few files as possible.

In the following example, I want to delete any other file in `/tmp/tmp/`, except for `btrfs_x64.efi` and `iso9660_x64.efi`.

```
$ refind_efi_dir='/tmp/tmp/'
$ drivers=('btrfs_x64.efi' 'iso9660_x64.efi')
$ find ${refind_efi_dir}drivers_x64/ "${drivers[@]/#/! -name }" -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

I want the expansion to expand to the following command:

```
$ find /tmp/tmp/drivers_x64/ ! -name btrfs_x64.efi ! -name iso9660_x64.efi -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

But instead it appears to be running the following command:

```
$ find /tmp/tmp/drivers_x64/ "! -name btrfs_x64.efi" "! -name iso9660_x64.efi" -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Is there a way to get the former? Ideally it also works if some array entries have spaces in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here you need to generate 3 arguments to `find` for each element of your array. Also `find`'s `-name` takes a pattern, so for it to match on exact file names, you'd need to escape the `find` wildcard operators (`*`, `?`, `[` and `\`):

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#m)
exclusions=()
for name ($drivers) exclusions+=(! -name ${name//(#m)[?*[\\]/\\$MATCH})

find ${refind_efi_dir}drivers_x64/ $exclusions -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

`"${array[@]/pattern/replacement}"` expands to as many elements as there are in the array, after substitution performed on each of them.

Here, given that `-name` takes a file *name* pattern, it should not contain `/`, so you could replace each element with `!/-name/element` and then split on `/`:

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#m)
find ${refind_efi_dir}drivers_x64/ \
  ${(@s[/])${drivers//(#m)[?*[\\]/\\$MATCH}/#/!\/-name\/} \
  -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Or use `$'\0'` instead of `/` as it can't be passed in an argument to an external command anyaway:

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#m)
find ${refind_efi_dir}drivers_x64/ \
  ${(@0)${drivers//(#m)[?*[\\]/\\$MATCH}/#/!$'\0'-name$'\0'} \
  -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

But that doesn't help much with legibility...

Here, you could also use `zsh`'s glob for everything:

```
(cd -P -- $refind_efi_dir && rm -f -- **/^(${(~j[|])drivers})(D.))
```

Where the `j[|]` parameter expansion flag joins the elements of the `$drivers` array with `|` and `~` causes that `|` to be treated as a glob operator. That pattern is negated with `^` (for which you need the `extendedglob` option). `D` to include hidden files, `.` to restrict to regular files like your `-type f`.

Answer (score 2):

`"${drivers[@]/#/! -name }"` puts `! -name`  in the same shell word as each array element. `"${=drivers[@]/#/! -name }"` would split the results, so `!` and `-name` would end up as separate shell words, but the array elements would also be split at whitespace.

One solution is to abuse the `e` and `P` [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
find … /(e\''reply=($drivers)'\'P\''!'\'P\''-name'\') …
```

`/(…)` expands the glob pattern `/`, which always matches exactly one thing (the root directory), and applies the glob qualifiers to it. The glob qualifier `e` replaces each match by the new value of the array variable `reply`, which we set to the list of words we want to apply the subsequent glob qualifiers to. Then the glob qualifier `P`, used twice, inserts the specified text as separate words before each match.

In this specific case, [as Stéphane Chazelas showed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/651135), you can simply do everything with zsh globs, without using find.

Comment: `/(e['reply=($drivers)']P[!]P[-name])` would make it a bit more legible.